# jEditable TextArea, I need to maintain formatting on save but show user friendly text on edit (MVC3)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view, jeditable

I am using the jEditable plugin on a textarea in my program.  What I would like to do is when I click in the text area I would like to enter something like:
Do this first
Do this second
Do this third.

When I submit, I would like jEditable to keep the formatting I have in place, which my current textarea does, however when I click on the textarea to edit again, it displays the following:
Do this first
Do this second
Do this third.

I want to be able to click in the textarea again to edit and then have it show user friendly text, not the html that it does, but I need the formatting to remain in place.

Below is my javascript, view, and controller.  Any help would be great!

Javascript:

```
$(".textarea").editable("/ShoppingList/UpdateNotesReminders",
{
     type      : 'textarea',
     rows      : 7,
     columns   : 15,
     cancel    : 'Cancel',
     submit    : 'Save',
     method: 'POST',
     placeholder     : 'No Notes have been entered',
     callback: function(value, settings) { 
    var retval = value.replace(/\n/gi, "<br>"); 
    $(this).html(retval);
}
});
```

Action:

```
//This action is called when save button is clicked after editing notes and reminders.
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public string UpdateNotesReminders(string id, string value)
        {
            HttpCookie notesRemindersCookie = new HttpCookie("notesRemindersCookie");
            notesRemindersCookie.Value = value.Replace("<br>", "%0a");
            notesRemindersCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(notesRemindersCookie);
            return value;
        }
```

View:

```
<div class="textarea dynform" id="NotesReminders">@Html.Raw(Model.NotesReminders)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your post was stripped off of some HTML that you're trying to show...

But I think the solution to your problem is HTMLEncode/Decode the user contents.